# ajax post method in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send ajax post javascript variable to php. My code php will only be executed if I press submit in another form.
My code is in one `index.php` file.

The console shows that this value **has been sent**, but my php code does not want to pick it up and does not execute the query. Why?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['imie2'])) {

...

if(isset($_POST['item_id']) && !empty($_POST['item_id'])){
$value = $_POST['item_id'];

if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO zamowienia VALUES ('$value')")) {
...

?>


<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="imie2">
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var value = localStorage.getItem('sumalist');
        console.log(value);

        $.ajax({
            url:"index.php",
            method:"POST",

            data:{
                item_id: value,
            },
            success:function(response) {
                console.log('ok'); // console shows ok
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What does the response in the console show?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of passing values directly.

Comment: @Script47 console shows `ok`

Comment: No. That is what you have got it to show, what does the `response` show?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `$_POST['item_id']` being empty or the query not being executed? Aren't you missing some field names in your insert query?

Comment: `Undefined index: item_id`

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> if (isset($_POST['imie2'])) {
> ```

but your data looks like this:

> ```
> data:{
>    item_id: value,
> },
> ```

There's no `imie2` field so your test will always fail.

Comment: I have a imie2 field. just my code is executed after completing the form and pressing submit.

Comment: @A.Jo — You have one in your form, you do not have one in your JavaScript. I quoted the complete object you are sending. You can see there is no `imie2` there. That is why the form works by the JS doesn't!!